# EU Cyber Resilience Act - Conflicting Requirements?

Tags: security, development-process, requirements

As a fellow SW developer in EU, I hope that you know that there is a proposal for a new law, called **Cyber Resilience Act**, that will, if approved, will affect all digital products on the EU market.

In the proposal there is two annexes, I and II, that contains requirements on the product and the development of the product.

Under ANNEX I. 1.2 there is one requirement:

> Products with digital elements shall be delivered without any known
> exploitable vulnerabilities;

And under ANNEX I 2.1 there is another:

> Manufacturers of the products with digital elements shall: (1)
> identify and document vulnerabilities and components contained in the
> product, including by drawing up a software bill of materials in a
> commonly used and machine-readable format covering at the very least
> the top-level dependencies of the product;

My question is:
Are not those two requirements contradictory?

Or are the second requirement meant to be for when the product is on the market?

*And yes, I know that it's a proposal and are under subject for change, but for what I know any updates to the proposal has not yet been done.*

More info can be found here:

[Press release from EU](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/ip_22_5374)

[Proposal and annexes](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:52022PC0454)

Comment: The key difference between the two requirements is the timing. I understand that the first is about known at the time of the delivery. In other words, you're not supposed to deliver unsecure software. The second has no limit: it requires to keep this info up to date, i.e. if a new vulnerability is discovered, you disclose. Moreover it requires also to keep track of components. As a consequence, for 1 you're also suppose to make sure that components used do not bear vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every vulnerability is exploitable. 1.2 makes reference only to those that are known and are exploitable.

For example, an open port can be a vulnerability. Can it be exploited? Probably not. On the other hand, deploying a product that uses a vulnerable `log4j` version is prohibited by the document.

Comment: There are two kind of vulnerabilities: those that are exploitable, and those that are not YET. The problem is that many vulnerabilities are exploitable but that it's not known for while.